# Is there a way to modify/create new Keys in a PCollection during HBase Import using Beam?

Tags: java, hbase, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I would like to add a prefix/suffix to HBase keys during an Apache Beam Import job. Here is the code that creates the PCollection that holds the HBase data:

```
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(Utils.tweakOptions(opts));
    HBaseSnapshotInputConfigBuilder configurationBuilder =
        new HBaseSnapshotInputConfigBuilder()
            .setProjectId(opts.getProject())
            .setHbaseSnapshotSourceDir(opts.getHbaseSnapshotSourceDir())
            .setSnapshotName(opts.getSnapshotName())
            .setRestoreDirSuffix(opts.getJobName());

    PCollection<KV<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>> readResult =
        pipeline.apply(
            "Read from HBase Snapshot",
            HadoopFormatIO.<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>read()
                .withConfiguration(configurationBuilder.build()));

    // Somehow create a new PCollection with the transformed Key - derived from the PCollection above.
    PCollection<Mutation> copyResult = readResult.apply("Prefixes", ParDo.of(new TransformFn()));
```

During the PTransform, I receive the data as such:

```
  public void processElement(ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
    KV<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> kv = context.element();
    List<Cell> cells = checkEmptyRow(kv);
    if (cells.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }

    // Preprocess delete markers
    if (hasDeleteMarkers(cells)) {
      cells = preprocessDeleteMarkers(cells);
    }

    // Split the row into multiple puts if it exceeds the maximum mutation limit
    Iterator<Cell> cellIt = cells.iterator();

    while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
      Put put = new Put(kv.getKey().get());

      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS && cellIt.hasNext(); i++) {
        put.add(cellIt.next());
      }

      context.output(put);
    }
  }
```

Where would it be possible for me to update the Hbase Key? The HBase Put object needs to have the same key as context.element(), otherwise the Transform fails with:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Didn't receive a result for this mutation entry
```

It seems like PCollection -> ProcessContext -> HBase Put -> HBase Cell **all need to maintain the same key during import** ... Therefore I cannot modify the key after a PCollection has been created.

How could I go about creating a new PCollection that holds the same Hbase data but a different HBase key?

Comment: Clarification:

The end-goal is to receive Key:Data from HBase Import and transform to prefix_Key:Data in Beam, then output to target db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can't just copy a cell into a `Put` with a new key since that cell already contains the old row key.

From `Cell` Javadoc:

*Uniqueness is determined by the combination of row, column family, column qualifier, timestamp, and type.*

You need to create a new `Cell` with a new key, copy CF name, qualifier name, timestamp, value, etc into it and add this new cell to the new `Put` object.

PS: Btw, there is a dedicated `HbaseIO` in Beam that can be easier to use than `HadopFormatIO`.

Comment: Hi Alexey - thanks for the response. you're correct. I have to create a new Cell this way, and add it to a Put object that was instantiated with the new key. However, this new Put object with new Key still doesn't match the ProcessContext key created here `KV<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> kv = context.element();`. Therefore, when adding the new Put object with new Key via `context.output(put);` it fails with the error mentioned above: `InvalidArgumentException: Didn't receive a result for this mutation entry` ... because the old key is still in the `context` object.

Comment: essentially the key needs to be consistent across PCollection, ProcessContext, HBase Put, and HBase Cell - so if the goal is to update the key, I believe I need to start at the PCollection level

Comment: Hmm, let me try it on my side.

Comment: I was wrong - the error in my code was around using Cell .getFamilyArray(), .getQualifierArray() etc. when trying to create the cell around my new key. the code should be `cloneFamily()` and `cloneQualifier` etc.

Comment: Thanks for coming back! And I'm glad that, finally, it works for you.